# Docker - Error response from daemon: received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: docker, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to pull/run an image with the following command:

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 sonarqub
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable.
```

Answer (score 14):

The issue is not your end. Docker registry is down at the moment.

[image]

[status.docker.com](https://status.docker.com/pages/history/533c6539221ae15e3f000031)

You can check for docker-registry status, it should work once it back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it happens. I also faced this issue. I just reloaded the daemon and restarted the docker service. It solved this issue. You can use the below commands.

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload #THIS IS RESCUE COMMAND…
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
$ sudo systemctl status docker
```